# react-native linking library from github

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rabbitmq

1. i created empty project with `react-native init`
2. i install npm library from github `npm i kegaretail/react-native-rabbitmq#master --save`
3. i do some for lib install from readme, link and run on ios and everything is ok

but if i try to git clone this library to local folder and then
to `npm i ../react-native-rabbitmq --save` i get an error:

> react-native-rabbitmq link FAILED
>
> Could not automatically link package :Error: Cannot find module 'glob'

if i go to ../react-native-rabbitmq and do `npm i glob`, the error goes away, but build fails with error:

> /Users/lev/Projects/react-native-rabbitmq3/ios/RCTReactNativeRabbitMq/RCTReactNativeRabbitMq.m:3:9:
>   fatal error: 'RMQClient/RMQClient.h' file not found
>
> ## import
>
> ```
>     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated.
> ```

any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like react-native-rabbitmq has some pretty involved install/setup steps.  Did you do them all?  In particular, it requires you to tell XCode to set up a recursive search path to look for headers, which might explain your lack of header-finding.  https://github.com/kegaretail/react-native-rabbitmq

Comment: yes i did them all